# Emty line in the file ruins the code (python)

Tags: python

First save goes like in the file: 
 
Police: 911  
 swat.team: 912

And when loading the file and saving new inputs into the file looks like this:
Police: 911  
 swat.team: 912  
 
police.chef: 913

The extra empty line that happens causes the load function to crash when loading the file a second time when starting the basic program.

upon saving to the file for a second time it's meant to be like this:  
Police: 911  
 swat.team: 912  
police.chef: 913

I don't know how to fix this despite trying for a while. So maybe someone here knows?

The code below is just a small piece taken from the main code (and is most likely not properly intended)

```
lista = {"police":"911"}
functiontext = raw_input("call function ")
arguments = raw_input("input file name ")

def save(lista,arguments):
    filen = arguments
    spara = lista
    fil = open(filen + ".txt","w")

    for keys, values in spara.items():

        spara_content = keys + ": " + values + "\n"


        fil.write(spara_content)
        fil.close()
 def load(lista, arguments):
      filen = arguments
        ladda = open(filen + ".txt","r")
        for namesandnumbers in ladda:
       (key, val) = namesandnumbers.split(": ")
          lista[(key)] = val
          lista = ladda
          return lista

if functiontext == "1":
     save(lista,arguments)

if functiontext == "2":
    load(lista, arguments)
    print lista
```

Comment: Can you please fix your indenting? this way it's very difficult to infer what your code is actually supposed to do..

Comment: Do you actually have nested functions or is your indentation badly off in your question? In any case, wrap the failing code in a `try`/`except`.

Comment: Do you mean the code itself or ehm me trying to explain how it saves to the file?

Comment: The code. Indentation is critical in python, yours appears to be all over the place.

Comment: @roganjosh mostly the indention is badly made in the question... also the  code isn't actually failing... it just uploads to the file wrong.

Comment: We're not debating whether or not your code is badly indented in the question; in fact, we appear to agree on that. So, how do you expect us to understand how the current code works and help you when you post example code that would actually fail to run? You need to actually make sure your question reflects what your real code looks like.

Comment: @roganosh sorry i saw the problem now.